# Dashboard Widget CSS

Tags: wp-admin, dashboard

I want to add a class name to my custom dashboard widget but I've found no way to do this searching the codex. Right now the only class name on my widget is `postbox` (which is added in '/wp-admin/includes/template.php') but I would like to add more. How can I do this?

```
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', function () {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget('widget2','Graph','widget_2');

});

function widget_2($post){
    var_dump($post); /* string '' (length=0) */
    ?>
    <div id="graph-points-by-time" class="graph-points-by-time"></div>
    <br class="clear">
    <div id="graph-legend" class="graph-legend height-auto"></div>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`postbox_classes` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/postbox_classes_page_id/) as follow:

```
add_filter( 'postbox_classes_dashboard_widget2', function ( $classes ) {

   // $classes is an array; add your custom classes to the array
   $classes[] = 'my-class';

   return $classes;

} );
```